# sparklyr can't filter missing value of `sd` on single value

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

Applying `sd()` to a single value in a spark data frame (via sparklyr package in R) results in a missing value that cannot be filtered out based on it being a missing value.

Can someone explain this / provide a good solution?

Example below.

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
#> * Using Spark: 2.1.0

x <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "c"), x = c(1, 2, 3))

copy_to(sc, x, "tmp", overwrite = TRUE)
#> # Source:   table<tmp> [?? x 2]
#> # Database: spark_connection
#>     grp     x
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     a     1
#> 2     a     2
#> 3     c     3

x_tbl <- tbl(sc, "tmp") %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(x_sd = sd(x))

x_tbl
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
#> # Database: spark_connection
#> # Groups:   grp
#>     grp     x      x_sd
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     a     1 0.7071068
#> 2     a     2 0.7071068
#> 3     c     3       NaN

x_tbl %>% filter(!is.na(x_sd)) %>% collect()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp [2]
#>     grp     x      x_sd
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     a     1 0.7071068
#> 2     a     2 0.7071068
#> 3     c     3       NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of incompatibility between `sparklyr` and Spark. In Spark there are both `NULLS` (somewhat equivalent to R `NA`) and `NaNs`, each with different processing rules, but both values are fetched as `NaN` in `sparklyr`.

To filter out `NaN` you have to use [`isnan`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@isnan(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (don't confuse it with R `is.nan`):

```
x_tbl %>% filter(!isnan(x_sd)) %>% collect()
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   grp [1]
    grp     x      x_sd
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     a     1 0.7071068
2     a     2 0.7071068
```

To better illustrate the problem:

```
df <- copy_to(sc,
  data.frame(x = c("1", "NaN", "")), "df", overwrite = TRUE
) %>% mutate(x = as.double(x))

df %>% mutate_all(funs(isnull, isnan))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
      x isnull isnan
  <dbl>  <lgl> <lgl> 
1     1  FALSE FALSE
2   NaN  FALSE  TRUE
3   NaN   TRUE FALSE
```